# ANDROID -How to open camera when a button is pressed in android?

Tags: java, android, camera

I am a newbie in android application. When i clicked the button, the camera should appear. What should I do? What are the codes to be used? Please help, thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? We will help you debug your code, but will not write it for you. Please show an error, and something for us to help you with. Please edit your question to update this information.

Comment: just google something with the words "android" "intent" and "camera" and a bunch of useful info will be at your fingertips, in fact, dont even google, just do a stackoverflow search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 YourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
 @Override          
 public void onClick(View v) 
 {  

Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);

}         
});
```

The image will be automatically saved in a default directory.

And you need to set the permission for the camera in your `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> <uses-permission>
```

Comment: where should I put the Intent?

Comment: Write the image to a file too so you can use it

Answer (score 0):

on the Click of button use the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
  startActivity(intent);
```

in the manifest add the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" >
```